# Kendo UI grid can't be initialized from jquery when angular is present - throws "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

This one is fun...

I'm trying to use Kendo UI grid inside my angular app. I have tried using the grid directive but I'll need to manipulate the grid once it's created so I prefer using the jquery+custom directive method. 
The issue is simple to recreate. Once the html has ng-app, calling $("thegrid").kendoGrid(options) will fail with "undefined is not a function".

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/L3ps7hn2/7/

just remove the `ng-app` attribute from the parent `<div>` and it all works properly.

I assume this is a bug in the kendo ui code but I was wondering if anyone can think of a workaround for now so I can continue working.

Thanks!

Comment: Try with a newer version of KendoUI (see your example modified [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/L3ps7hn2/8/))

Comment: thanks! I thought I had the latest for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, thanks to @OnaBai's comment above, by using the latest KendoUI version.